# Subtraction of non-divisible pointer addresses

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Is subtraction of non-divisible pointer addresses defined in C? In C++?

Here's an example:

```
void* p = malloc(64);

int* one = (int*)((char*)p);
int* two = (int*)((char*)p + 7);

printf("%x %x %d %d\n", one, two, sizeof(int), two - one);
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/qHUk6N).

I get the output `8a94008 8a9400f 4 1`, so it seems like it does the division and truncates the remainder. Is the behavior defined?

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. The correct statement to print will be `printf("%p %p %zu %td\n", (void*)one, (void*)two, sizeof(int), two - one);`

Comment: I do not have a citation. Pointer arithmetic is based on integer arithmetic and that is well defined. So I think `two - one` is well defined. even if the pointers are not packed like a reasonable person would expect. On the other hand - do not do this, no one will spot this in your codebase.

Comment: Even just holding that pointer `two` in your program is invalid as the pointer does not satisfy the alignment constraints for `int` (though in practice on most hardware it won't trigger a fault until you actually try and dereference it on a processor that doesn't correct for unaligned memory access like ARM)

Comment: @Johannes `two - one` returns `ptrdiff_t` which may not be the same size as `int`, therefore printing it with `%d` invokes undefined behavior. It must be printed with `%td`. Similarly, `size_t` must be printed using `%zu`

Comment: `int* two = (int*)((char*)p + 7);` might seem to run in x86 but it'll give you segfault on most other architectures

Comment: @Johannes: No, pointer arithmetic isn't defined on integer arithmetic. (Proof: you can't add two pointers). It's defined so that arrays work. In particular, `a[n]` is `*(a+n)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is undefined behavior according to 5.7.6:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. [...] Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
>   one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

In your code, pointer `two` is not pointing to an element of the same `int` array as pointer `one`. In fact, it is not pointing to any array element of `p`, because it points to the "middle" of one of the elements (which in itself is an undefined behavior).

Comment: This is true, but UB happens the first time in `(int*)((char*)p + 7)`.

Comment: @user694733 Are you sure that an invalid cast causes UB even without a dereference? I was trying to find something to this effect in the standard, but I didn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: You are allowed to convert pointer from malloc to any builtin pointer type. However, for `(char*)p + 7` it no longer holds, conversion from `char*` to `int*` is invalid.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You probably know that the C standard accomodates hardware which traps on merely loading unaligned pointers into a register.

Comment: @MSalters: More significantly, if a pointer of a type requiring alignment is passed directly or indirectly to memcpy, a compiler is entitled to generate code that will fail if the pointer in question is not properly aligned; the justification for such compiler behavior comes from the fact that generating the improperly-aligned pointer invoked UB, since memcpy() itself would have no other legitimate reason to impose alignment requirements.

Answer (score 19):

Under some assumptions<sup>1</sup>, in C the third line:

```
int* two = (int*)((char*)p + 7);
```

already causes undefined behavior, because the pointer p isn't correctly aligned for the type it is referencing<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The assumption is that alignment requirements for type int are be higher than for type char. This is true on most moderns architectures. Since all alignments must be powers of two<sup>3</sup> and the value 7 isn't, the addition of that value to the pointer p cannot produce a pointer with an alignment that is as strict as is the alignment requirement for type int.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.3.2.3 Pointers 7.)
A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined.

<sup>3</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.8 Alignment of objects 4.)
Every valid
alignment value shall be a nonnegative integral power of two.

Comment: I can't find chapter and verse at the moment, but the same is going to be true of C++.  The calculation of `two` will be undefined behaviour.  (Imagine a word based machine with special registers for pointers.  Calculating `two` will go through one of these registers, and it might barf at the misaligned pointer - such machines have existed in the past.)